# Complex Query Limited SQL Knowledge

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im trying to write what I believe is a rather complicated SQL query but Im working with limited SQL knowledge.  I have this query:

```
 SELECT 
   analysisvalue.analysisid, 
   heatname, 
   analysistime, 
   sampletype,
   grade, 
   productid, 
   element, 
   value 
 FROM 
   dbo.AnalysisValue 
 INNER JOIN 
   dbo.CAnalysis 
 ON 
   dbo.AnalysisValue.AnalysisID = dbo.CAnalysis.AnalysisID
 WHERE 
   heatname = 'A7M0066' 
 ORDER BY 
   analysisvalue.analysisid ASC, 
   element
```

and this query:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  S_analysis 
WHERE 
  heat_no = 'A7M0066'
```

I need to modify the second query to also include * from S_analysis WHERE heat_no = 'A7M0066' but also all records including those without that heat_no where analysis_datetime is between the analysis time of the last record from the first query and two hours that follow that time.

The S_analysis table structure for the second query is:

```
analysis_datetime(datetime, not null)
heat_no(varchar(7), not null)
comment(varchar(40), null)
Then about 30 other columns of type (real, null)
```

The table structure of AnalysisValue in the first query is:

```
AnalysisID(int, not null)
Element(char(9), not null)
Value(real, null)
```

The table structure of CAnalysis in the first query is:

```
AnalysisID(PK, int, not null)
HeatName(char(7), null)
AnalysisTime(datetime, null)
SampleType(char(5), null)
Grade(char(4), null)
ProductID(char(14), null)
```

Comment: Kindly include the table structure

Comment: @praveen I have added the table structure above

Answer (score 0):

Since you need only top row from your 1st query .You can use `Cross join` with the 2nd query to get the desired result

```
 ;with cte as 
(SELECT 
 analysisvalue.analysisid, 
 heatname, 
 analysistime, 
 sampletype,
 grade, 
 productid, 
 element, 
 value 
 FROM 
 dbo.AnalysisValue 
 INNER JOIN 
 dbo.CAnalysis 
 ON 
 dbo.AnalysisValue.AnalysisID = dbo.CAnalysis.AnalysisID
 WHERE 
 heatname = 'A7M0066' 
 )
 SELECT 
      * 
 FROM 
 S_analysis s
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 analysistime
 FROM cte
 ORDER BY analysisid desc
 ) c
 WHERE s.heat_no = 'A7M0066' OR
 (s.analysis_datetime BETWEEN c.analysistime AND DATEADD(hh, 2, c.analysistime ))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but Im not sure what you mean by I only need one row from my first query.  The first query I posted above returns over 150 rows currently which is correct.  I will try your solution

Comment: Im currently receiving these errors:Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.

Comment: use `;` before `With` statement

Comment: @HendPro12:Since you specified `analysis time of the last record from the first query` .therefore i suggested use cross join as you need only last record from the 1st query

Comment: I placed a ; before with which gives me a syntax error.  Why would I place a semi-colon prior to the first line of sql?

Comment: The semicolon is just there to ensure you are not continuing a line from another query.  iirc SQL server does not allow order by inside a cte.

Comment: @ChrisTravers:Thanks .I have rectified the query now

Comment: @HendPro12 :Updated my query

Comment: @praveen Not sure why but with the semicolon I still receive Line 1: Incorrect syntax near ';'. and when I remove the semicolon I get: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.

Comment: Do you have any other queries on top of `With` clause .Becz if i execute the above sql ,it executing perfectly fine

Comment: @praveen No, it is a blank query window.  Actually I just tried your code in Fiddle, it runs perfectly but not in SQL Server for some reason

Comment: Oh then i rather suggest close sql server once and open it again .That might help u :)

Comment: @praveen  Just closed and re-opened SQL Server.  I received the same error when I re-executed the query

Answer (score 0):

Try this (never used `sql-server`, but it should produce your expected results)

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  S_analysis 
  CROSS JOIN 
  ( 
    SELECT TOP 1
      analysistime
    FROM 
       dbo.CAnalysis 
    WHERE 
       heatname = 'A7M0066' 
    ORDER BY 
      analysistime DESC ) c
WHERE 
  heat_no = 'A7M0066'
  OR ( heat_no IS NULL AND s.analysis_datetime BETWEEN c.analysistime AND DATEADD(hh, 2, c.analysistime ) )
```

Comment: @HendPro12 I have not tested it, there could be some basic Syntax errors, but the logic should be fine

Comment: @HendPro12 I have tried to correct the syntax, please chk now

Comment: I uploaded the code again into another query window with the same result.  After a cross comparison of the queries I could find no differences.

Comment: Didn't get what you meant by ` same result`, you could create a demo table structre on sqlfillde, as I am not are of SQLSERVER syntax

Comment: By same result I mean, that I retried with your new corrected syntax and still got the error:Line 15: Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'

Comment: Did you really use the updated `SQL`? there's no `LIMIT` in the updated `SQL` !